# Unable to install .NET Framework 3.5 through SCCM on Windows 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, .net-3.5, sccm

I recently had to uninstall/re-install .NET Framework 3.5 on my new Windows 10 work machine to troubleshoot another issue.  I have to install it via SCCM due to Group Policy blocking Windows Updates (so I can't just install via Control Panel > Turn Features On/Off).

When attempting to re-install through SCCM the install just spins in the Installing state indefinitely until it times out.

Steps taken:

- Uninstalled the .NET 3.5 Framework via Turn Windows Features On and Off in Control Panel and restarted machine.
- Went to SCCM and attempted to install software, and it hung indefinitely.
- After 2 hours I restarted machine to check if I just wasn't alerted it was finished for some reason
- Install did not finish, Failed status shows with the error code for timeout in SCCM.

Other Info:

- I verified no errors were generated in the SCCM log files or Event Viewer.
- I can't install via Control Panel MS Update download as mentioned above due to Group Policy, I can't do an Offline install b/c these laptops don't have a disk drive (for whatever reason that was decided to be ok), and I can't do a system restore to before I removed it due to drive encryption software.
- No admin accounts or similar can get different results, and I've verified it is not the SCCM install itself after getting it to install on another machine just fine.
- I've ran both the .NET Framework Repair tools and Clean-up tools and I still get the issue.

Any ideas on what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters a situation similar, I was able to fix it by extracting the microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab file from the .iso of Windows 10.

Using that file you can run the following script in an elevated (administrator) powershell and it will install the files offline for you.

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:<path to file>
```